# How do I check which user on a Linux system?

Tags: javascript, node.js

It is necessary to check on what behalf the program works, if from root then continue code execution, if from a normal user, then run the bash command through child process?

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look at [os.userInfo](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_userinfo_options), for example:

```
const os = require("os");

let userInfo = os.userInfo();
console.log("User info:", userInfo);
// Root user uid will always be 0
if (userInfo.uid === 0) {
    console.log("User is root.")
}
```

This will give you details such as username, uid, gid, shell, and homedir.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the script was executed with `root` you can use [`process.getuid()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_getuid)

```
if(process.getuid() === 0) {
   console.log('root user');
   // do something
} else {
   console.log('No root user')
   // dome something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but if the user is not a root, then I need to execute this git clone code https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent-desktop.git torrent; cd torrent; npm install; npm run package, that is, it turns out like this?

Comment: 'var exec = require ('child_process'). exec, child;
if (process.getuid () === 0)
    child = exec ('git clone https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent-desktop.git torrent; cd torrent; npm install; npm run package',
     function (error, stdout, stderr) {
         console.log ('stdout:' + stdout);
         console.log ('stderr:' + stderr);
         if (error! == null) {
              console.log ('exec error:' + error);
         }
     });
  child ();'

Comment: Do one thing or the other depending on the result from `.getuid`... just `if/else`. Check updated answer

Comment: Yes, but how to make sure that when the application starts, this command should be executed first, then all the rest, how to do it?

Comment: For example:

`if (process.getuid () === 0) {
    console.log ('root user');
    // do something
} else {
    console.log ('No root user')
    exec ('bash -c git clone https://github.com/**', function (error, stdOut, stdErr)
}`

If the exec command did not work, then the application terminates

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to check if the user is `root` use `process.getuid` or `os.userInfo`, it seems you have an additional question regarding programming logic.